# asp:TextBox Disabled style is not consistent in different Browsers

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET

When `TextBox1.Enabled = false;` it has a gray background in FF3, but no change in IE8 or Chrome. So it's harder to tell if it's disabled or not. Is there any more general way to make the disable textbox rendered more consistent on a top-level? So I don't need to change this for every page or every website? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could set a CSS style to handle disabled text controls to render them consistently.  For example, something like the following:

```
input[type="text"][disabled] {
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    border: solid 1px #7F9DB9; 
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

For IE7 support (and possibly even IE8), a `!DOCTYPE` must be specified or CSS attribute selectors will not work.  Unfortunately, if you require support for IE6 this will not work and you have to use a CSS class on any text input instead.

Comment: You should also specify the border and font color styles as well: `border: solid 1px #7F9DB9; color: #CCC` since the plethora of browsers will no doubt change any number of these. For IE6 you may have to use a class like @squillman suggests, but who cares ;-)

Comment: Both valid points, and I've updated accordingly.  Thanks for pointing out IE6; as much as I try to ignore it, it doesn't seem to go away.

Comment: This seems not working for me. I added <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> in my aspx file. However, if taking out the disable key, input[type="text"] does work. What could be wrong?

Comment: Also tried input[disabled], this works too. So looks like input[type="text"][disabled] doesn't work for somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a CSS class to it using the `CssClass` property and control it as much as you want.

More on the CssClass property [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Sample CSS:

```
.DisabledTextBox {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border: solid 1px #A0A0A0;
  color: #A0A0A0;
}
```

Then use the CssClass like this:

```
<asp:TexbBox id="DisabledTextBox" CssClass="DisabledTextBox" value="Some Value" />
```

Comment: @Dennis Wow, that's some pretty good company there.  Thanks :)